# alpha channel and RGB channel aren't separating correctly

Tags: texturing

[image]

i have a test image texture here,
i painted on it with random colors and erased alpha as you can see on the top left corner in the image editor.
in the shader editor [bottom left], when i connect the image to a viewer node or the principled shader i get the colors plus the alpha as shown in the left half of the whole image,
but on the right half when the alpha output is hooked to some node i get the right view of my image without the alpha.

Comment: I am very confused, why are you addind Alpha value to Math node?

Comment: What do you mean by "the RGB colors appear correctly"? On the right side there is no alpha information, it's completely opaque. So if you don't want any alpha transparency, why is there alpha information in the image?

Comment: sorry for the confusion , I'll edit the question to more clear

Comment: hope its clearer now

Comment: @gordon-brinkmann its the same image ,same result, the only difference is that the alpha output is busy with another node

Comment: Hmm if all else is exactly the same, this looks like a bug and should be reported to the bug tracker

Comment: @Gorgious I'm quite sure you're right, this is a bug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:** This answer was referring to the first wording of your question, where it sounded like you were taking the preview on the left with black areas as incorrect display, and the one on the right without black areas as incorrect display. Now it seems you're aware that the black areas have to be there - then it's simply a bug.

Old answer:

What you have done is setting the *Blend* type of the brush to *Erase Alpha* and painted some strokes - the ones appearing in black on the left image and transparent in the *Image Editor* window. This is because *Erase Alpha* paints black in the *Alpha Channel*, meaning the white parts where the image is opaque will be painted black, so the image is transparent in these areas.

The *Image Editor* displays transparency correctly. Your *3D Viewport* however is set to *Material Preview* - in this mode transparency appears black, because the default setting of the preview cannot display transparency.

Somehow (and this might be a bug), plugging the *Alpha* output into some other input (doesn't have to be a *Math* node) makes the *Material Preview* ignore the alpha information. But this is actually not "correct" as you think, because there is an alpha mask which is now ignored.

You can tell that the behaviour of ignoring the alpha mask when plugging into some other node might be a bug, because deleting this other node doesn't bring back the alpha information, you have to re-plug the image into the viewer node.

This happens only in *Material Preview* mode, if you switch to *Rendered View*, the areas remain black - which is correct, since the texture is transparent there, the color informations of these areas are not visible. Because you don't have a *Transparency BSDF* mixed in with the alpha, the black areas stay opaque.

Comment: yes a a bug is more likely , i thought the alpha channel overlays as 4th layer , but like you said in the first answer, it just paint black .thanks.

Comment: @wafi Well, the colors are in the RGB channels, so painting in the alpha channel cannot overlay the colors. And it only paints black in the alpha channel, it actually paints transparent and would show underlying textures - but you have no underlying texture there.